# C++ Code keeps crashing after a validation

Tags: c++, string, validation

I have written a piece of code to validate a keyword, it validates and makes sure that the word is 5 letters long and it is all letters with no numbers in it. However, when I run it, the code seems to stop working at all and doesn't prompt me for the next question, I've tested it without this code and this part of the code is the problem, as it works fine without it.

The code:

```
            cout<<name1<<", please enter the keyword (5 characters): "<<endl;
            cin>>key;
            for(int i = 0; i < keylength; i++){
                if(isalpha(key[i]) == 1){
                    validnum += 1;
                }
            }
            if(validnum == keylength && key.length() == keylength){
                validated = true;
            }
            else{
                validated = false;
            }
```

Comment: Where are you setting keylength?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @dominickator If the user will enter less than keylength characters then the code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @dominickator What type of variable is `key`?  If it's a `std::string`, then the entire test is: `bool validated = (key.size() == 5 && std::all_of(key.begin(), key.end(), ::isalpha));`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `key` is a string.

Comment: @Taekahn I'm setting keylength at the beginning of my main function, it is a const int of 5.

Comment: When seeking help on something like this, it should be helpful to show what you do afterward with values like `validated`, or how you set `keylength`. If validated is false does the program simply exit, for example? Your validity check may be the issue, then.

Comment: @EthanMcTague if validated is false, it will go into a while loop which will prompt the user for a keyword which meets the conditions (5 characters and all letters) and once it gets those conditions met, the loop will terminate and the program will move on.

Comment: `isalpha` returns 0 for non-alphabetic characters and non-zero for alphabetic characters.it does not necessarily return 1. The right way to check it is `if(isalpha(key[i]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the for loop you need to check that `key.length()` is equal to `keyLength`. Otherwise the loop can invoke undefined behavior when the user enters a string with the length less than `keyLength`.

Also the function `isalpha` does not necessary returns 1. It can return any positive value.

Change your code something like the following

```
validated = key.length() == keyLength;

if ( validated )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < keyLength && isalpha( ( unsigned char )key[i] ) ) ++i;

    validated = i == keyLength;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it was the fact that I wasn't checking for `key.length()` equaling `keylength` before the for loop ran, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no need for any loops to determine if the key is 5 characters and is all alphabetic.

Using [std::all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) will test if all the characters are alphabetic:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

bool isValidData(const std::string& key)
{
   return key.size() == 5 && std::all_of(key.begin(), key.end(), ::isalpha);
}
    
int main()
{
   //Test data  
   std::string testKeys[] = {"1abcdef", "abcde", "abcdefghijkl", "a", "xyzab"};

   for (size_t i = 0; i < std::size(testKeys); ++i)
   { 
       // Output results
       std::cout << testKeys[i] << " " << (isValidData(testKeys[i])?"OK":"BAD") << "\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
1abcdef BAD
abcde OK
abcdefghijkl BAD
a BAD
xyzab OK
```

Also, if you took a look at your code, it is not clear what the goal of the code is without running the code.  Compare that to the function `isValidData`: if you say what that function has in it, it reads almost as your description:

"The key size must be 5, and all of the characters must be alpha".